# Firebase sendSignInLinkToEmail taking ages to send email to user

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Hi I am currently using firebase's `sendSignInLinkToEmail` to send a passwordless sign up to a user so they can authenticate. However, currently it is taking a minute or two to send an email to the user. I was wondering why this is and how I can increase the speed at which it does this. Thanks all help is welcome.

Comment: I have the same issue. I can't figure out why, it seems to be more slow for gmail than other email providers and also it goes back to normal speed after the first successful sing in email link delivery. Is that same for you?

Comment: @dcx86 Yeah I'm having the exact same issue as you. if you do find a fix do say. thanks

Comment: @dcx86 This link seems helpful I have not fully gone through it yet https://support.google.com/mail/thread/13460853?hl=en